# PowerPoint for iPad - no audio?

Tags: audio, microsoft-powerpoint, ipad

I downloaded PowerPoint for iPad and uploaded one of my presentations that has audio in it. However, when I ran the presentation, I was unable to hear the audio. Everything else worked just fine though.

I am wondering if PowerPoint for iPad supports audio in presentations, and if it does, how can I modify my presentation to play audio? I'm pretty sure the volume slider was up.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wondering the same thing, but it looks like it does not support audio.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/compare-powerpoint-for-ipad-with-powerpoint-for-mac-and-powerpoint-for-windows-HA103762595.aspx

Keynote for iPad will play audio from Powerpoint presentations though.

Answer (score -1):

Several people seem to have issues with Audio not being played on their ipad, but if you plug something into the headphone jack like headphones or an external speaker, then the audio comes through on that. Some people on ipads with a mute switch also mention that turning off the mute switch may make a difference as powerpoint looks at the notification volume instead of playback volume like most apps do. I'm using an ipad without a mute button and still haven't figured out how to get the audio from a powerpoint to play on my ipad, but it does work via headphones.